# Why does this work? Spotify API call node.js

Tags: node.js, spotify

I am new to node and am working on an API call via node.js and am kinda confused why this works. I have done other API calls via node with ease as it was easy to figure out how to target the various fields etc.. but I never got a link with the spotify API and am confused how data.tracks.items.artists.name gave me the artist name?

I know this is an ignorant question but I really want to understand how this works not just make it work.

```
function song() {
var nodeArgs = process.argv;
var SongName = "";
for (var i = 3; i < nodeArgs.length; i++) {
    if (i > 3 && i < nodeArgs.length) {
        SongName = SongName + "+" + nodeArgs[i];
    }
    else {
        SongName += nodeArgs[i];
    }
}

var Spotify = require('node-spotify-api');
var spotify = new Spotify({
    id: "id",
    secret: "secret"
});

spotify.search({ type: 'track', query: SongName, limit: 1 }, function (err, data) {
    if (err) {
        SongName = "";
        console.log("Artist: " + songData.artists[0].name);
        console.log("Song Title: " + songData.name);
        console.log("Preview Track: " + songData.preview_url);
        console.log("Album: " + songData.album.name);
        song();
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < data.tracks.items.length; i++) {
        var songData = data.tracks.items[i];
        console.log("Artist: " + songData.artists[0].name);
        console.log("Song Title: " + songData.name);
        console.log("Preview Track: " + songData.preview_url);
        console.log("Album: " + songData.album.name);
    }
});
}
```

Comment: If you want to understand how the library works, you could look into its source code in its github repo (https://github.com/ceckenrode/node-spotify-api)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short Answer - 
the track api endpoint responds with the `Object Model` which also contains artist objects - which is an array of artist objects, where the artist object contains the key `name`.

ref: https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/reference/tracks/get-track/

From their API docs

> GET https://api.spotify.com/v1/tracks/{id}

the response object contains

```
KEY VALUE       | TYPE                   | VALUE DESCRIPTION
---
artists         | an array of simplified | The artists who performed the track. 
                | artist objects         | information about the artist.
```

#### Artist Object

```
artist object (simplified)

KEY VALUE       | TYPE                   | VALUE DESCRIPTION
---
external_urls   | an external URL object | Known external URLs for this artist.
href            | string                 | A link to the Web API endpoint providing full details of the artist.
id              | string                 | The Spotify ID for the artist.
name            | string                 | The name of the artist
type            | string                 | The object type: "artist"
uri             | string                 | The Spotify URI for the artist.
```

Comment: Got it that linked helped a lot. Maybe it’s lack of sleep but I guess I glossed over that when reading the documentation. Thanks